# How to set AD Home folders in an Azure AD environment

Tags: active-directory, azure, azure-activedirectory

I'm looking to set Home folders for our Azure AD environment. When I try to set it in Active Directory Users and Computers, it is grayed out.

I was thinking I might have to set it through the web interface but I can not find any option for it.

[Active Directory Users and Computers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSdBl.png)

Comment: As I known , there is no Azure AD Home folder. How did you set it? Can you show me a screenshot for it?

Comment: Wayne, I am looking to set the Azure AD Home Folder. I was not able to set it. I was wondering if I was just missing something. Looks like I will have to set it using a logon GPO script.